# Selenium: WebDriver: double click div, and then input text always failed

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

the page source code is

```
    <div title="Double Click here to Edit">
    <span>Double Click here to Edit...</span>    
    </div>
    <button name="OK"/>
```

After double click it from UI, the following html code will be added to this div

```
    <label id="ll">
    <span>
    <input class="field" type="text" text()='test'>
    </span>
    </label>
```

then we can input text, after clicking other place on the UI, the div text will be changed:

```
    <div title="Double Click here to Edit">
       test
    </div>
    <button name="OK"/>
```

I want use the Selenium to simulate these operation, but always failed:

```
     method#1:         
     action.moveToElement(element).doubleClick().build().perform();
     element.sendKeys("test");

     method#2
     js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHtml='test';", element);
```

Anybody has idea about this issue?

Comment: What does the button do? Odds are the page is reloading and therefore resetting the value back.

Comment: Hi [~Fi Horan], I didn't describe it clearly before. Actually, the action flow should be, double click the div, and then there will be an input box displayed, then I can input text into it. but now ,when I use selenium to do that, it does not work. my code is  action.moveToElement(element).doubleClick().build().perform(); and then sendKeys, but it does not work

Comment: Don't supposed you can share the link to this page so we can take a look?